# Using the same domain for React and C# app locally

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net

I have created a ASP.NET Core app with a React front-end, using the [ASP.NET React Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022). When I run the application the ASP.NET API will run on port `7276` while the React app will run on port `5173`. This means that I cannot use relative URL's from my React app towards the API. E.g.

`/api/auth/login`

...doesn't work. I would have to do:

`https://localhost:7276/api/auth/login`

...instead (how this problem affects the app when deployed to the cloud, is not in scope of this question).

I could of course use the full URL, but I feel like it shouldn't be necessary. Also, based on this [tutorial on BFFs for C# React apps](https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet/#Securing-the-React-Application) (based on the older template), it seems that it should work with relative links.

Is there a way to configure the ASP.NET Core React App, so that calling relative URLs in the React part, will target the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new template uses a proxy for development environment. This proxy is running within the frontend Node and is configured in the `vite.config.js`. The proxy will proxy the traffic intended for the backend to the asp.net running on port 7276, so you never have to refer to that port.

So indeed you can use `https://localhost:5173/api/auth/login` or for that matter  a relative URL.

However, by default the proxy is configured only for the `WheatherForeCast` controller, so you will have to add your controller paths to the proxy configuration.

```
// vite.config.js
server: {
     proxy: {
         '^/weatherforecast': {  // <-- add or replace your paths
             target: 'https://localhost:7276/',
             secure: false
         }
     },
     port: 5173,
     https: {
         key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
         cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Have to try that later. Does that mean that I have to add every single path I use from my API, or is there a way to add groups?

Comment: I think if you use `/api` it will proxy all calls beginning with `api`. For more details please see [vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy)